# Toggle box wont work with button, but works with paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a toggle menu, however when i insert a `<button>` tag instead of a `<p>` tag the whole menu doesn't work, but it works with `<p>`.

How can i solve this problem?

**Snippet:**

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('menu-box');
  if (menuBox.style.display == "block") { // if is menuBox displayed, hide it
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  } else { // if is menuBox hidden, display it
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="infobox2">
  <form action="index.html" method="get">
    <p onclick="toggleMenu()" id="menu"> Skapa konto </p>
    <ul id="menu-box" style="display: block">
      <li><a href="index.html">Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="animal.html">Animal</a></li>
      <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because the form is using the button, try researching a bit on javascript events and how to 'prevent' them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default behaviour of a button tag is to send the form. This is why the page is being reloaded. If you don't want the button to send the form, you have to specify a `type` attribute.

```
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
```

Further reading:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Especially this part:

> Tip: Always specify the type attribute for the  element.
>   Different browsers may use different default types for the 
>   element.

Comment: Why should OP _"always specify the type attribute"_? Where is this assumption coming from?

Comment: World Wide Web Consortium

Comment: [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type) just speaks about a list of types and about a default type (submit) if no type has been explicitly stated. Where is the type attribute defined as mandatory?

Comment: have you read the html specifications? Your answer provide a solution and this is ok. It is just your tip to be wrong as it is not stated anywhere (also the browser different behaviour). Or you disagre also with the W3C consortium :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to prevent the default behaviour for the button . Just add `return false` in your function.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('menu-box');
  if (menuBox.style.display == "block") { // if is menuBox displayed, hide it
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  } else { // if is menuBox hidden, display it
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="infobox2">
  <form action="index.html" method="get">
    <p onclick="toggleMenu()" id="menu"> Skapa konto </p>
    <button onclick="toggleMenu()" id="menu1">Skapa konto1</button>
    <ul id="menu-box" style="display: block">
      <li><a href="index.html">Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="animal.html">Animal</a></li>
      <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is overkill. If you don't want some button to submit the form, you can change the type.

Comment: this is not true at all. It is a javascript way to do the task compared to an html one. They are completely alternative. Also please do not downvote an answer only because you don't agree with that

Comment: I disagree. I downvoted the answer because I believe it leads the OP in the wrong direction. Take it easy.